# Unable to browse to webapp host using owin

Tags: .net, owin

```
         const string url = "https://+:4343/";
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nServer listening at {0}. Press enter to stop", url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I was able to run this code successfully in first and second workstations. But fail in the 3rd workstation, I'm not sure if there is additional Microsoft component i miss out? I cant figure out how to solve this because i don't get any error when i run the code.

Comment: Are you able to browse url directly from browser (IE/Firefox etc) ? May be your url link is blocking by antivirus or firewall ?

Comment: I did tried different browser, result were same. But i was able to host web app inside IIS. I try different port also no issue,so i believe its not firewall or antivirus issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was struggling a day in a different way. Found out it actually success with http, so the problem is https. I found out this port is not exist when I do

> netsh http show sslcert

So after i create ssl for it. It able to run without issue.